# android: Use openOrCreateDatabase from within non activity class

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, class

I am creating a new class for database, the first function is to access the database 
the problem is that I always get error on MODE_PRIVATE

I tried to pass the context as parameter but still shows error

anyone know how to access the database from a non activity class

```
public class DB {

    public void OpenDB(Context ctx, SQLiteDatabase dataB)
    {

        dataB = openOrCreateDatabase("Schlogger", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
dataB = openOrCreateDatabase("Schlogger", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

to

```
dataB = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("Schlogger", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

`openOrCreateDatabase` is a method of `Context` class so you need a object of `Context` to call it.

Answer (score 2):

use `context` to open databse `ctx.openOrCreateDatabase("Schlogger", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE,null);`